# ¿Obtener datos de la base datos Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

intento traer datos de firebase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigo:

```
  function getClient(key)
  {
    var client;
    db.child("Client")
      .on('value', function(snapshot){
        client = snapshot.child(key).val()
        console.log("1", client)
      });
    console.log("2", client)
    return client;
  }
```

el código retorna null. 
hice varias pruebas y si trae el valor pero al salir de la función .on() no se guarda el valor en `Client` alguna solucion?

este es el resultado en la consola:
1- es cuando obtiene los valores. 
2- antes de retornar el client
supongo que se hacen en dos procesos diferentes ya que primero sale el 2 y luego el uno

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué pruebas hiciste? ¿Un console.log debajo de esto: `Client = snapshot.child(key).val();`  en el `on`,  te imprime algo? `console.log(Client);` Por cierto, `Client`  es para ti una variable o estás intentando crear una nueva instancia de una clase? Si es una variable ponlo en minúscula, por motivos de convención de nombres. Si funciona ahí, muestra el código donde dices que no te funciona.

Comment: @A.Cedano no me funciona en la parte de retornar el valor

Comment: Si pones esto dentro del `on` debería funcionar: **`return client;`**. La imagen indica que la variable funciona dentro del `on`, no fuera.

Comment: retorna el codigo en string

Answer (score 0):

Yo tambien tuve ese problema y lo pude solucionar no usando la función .on() ya que funciona pero para consultar sino la función .once() que si me permitió retornar los datos como necesitaba y el Object.keys() simplemente para darles formato ya que no viene tipo lista sino tipo objeto y el id lo puedo manejar fácilmente al igual que el objeto completo.

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
        
    export class ReserveService {
        reserveListTable!: AngularFireList<any[]>;
        
          constructor(
            private db: AngularFireDatabase
          ) { }
        
        async getListValidReserveUser(user: string) {
            let list: any;
            await this.db.list('/reserves/valid').query.orderByChild('user').equalTo(user).once('value', snapshot => {
              list = snapshot.val();
            });
            list = Object.keys(list).map(key => list[key]);
            return list;
          }
    }
```

espero les sirva la info.